# Divs wont appear side by side?

Tags: html, css

Why wont the following divs appear side by side? http://jsfiddle.net/YxCK4/

I'm trying to make it look like the following...

```
___________________________
| left|                   |
|     |                   | 
|     |         main      |     <--- Window.
|     |                   |
|     |                   |
|-------------------------|
```

Comment: Because divs by default are block level elements.

Comment: You need to use css float to make block elements such as div appear next to each other. Here's an update of your fiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/YxCK4/12/

Comment: @TJ. You don't *need* to use floats, but they are one of the most common techniques to achieve this.

Comment: I suggest that if you want to go further with HTML and CSS, complete some tutorials. There are plenty of these on the net. We cannot really help here if you are not willing to familiarize yourself with the most basic concepts.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: I'm well aware of that, as much as I'm aware of the drawbacks of display: inline and display: inline-block which I don't consider as a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Display the `<div>`'s as an `inline-block` or `float` them `left`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YxCK4/9/)

Something like this:

```
#window{
    width: 90%;
}

#left{
 padding: 10px; 
 width: 85px;  
    display: inline-block;
}

#main{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Block level elements don't naturally side next to each other, you have to define that behavior manually. Just define both divs as `float:left` to place them side by side, e.g.

```
#left, #main { float:left }
```

Answer (score 0):

Divs are block level elements, you need to use inline elements, like span or override with CSS float : left

Answer (score 0):

Now it does [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuBWT/embedded/result/), as others have said, both containers #left and #main needs to be floated + you can't assigne 90% width other if that width is more than the available space as it would take in float, it will automatically move itself down ans it must first try to set its with correct. I added this

```
#left,#main 
{
float:left
}

#main
{
width:300px; // 90% is not correct here and will not work
}
```